# Error while using of scipy.optimize.fmin_bfgs

Tags: numpy

My code look like this:

```
theta0 = np.array([0,0,0])
print(X.shape)
print(Y.shape)
print(theta0.shape)

(100, 2)
(100,)
(3,)

def logistic_func(theta, x):
    m, n = x.shape
    x = np.hstack((np.ones(x.shape[0]).reshape(x.shape[0], 1), x))
    s = np.dot(theta, x.T)
    s = np.where(np.abs(np.sum(theta*x, axis=1)) > 18, s, np.sign(s)*18)
    f = 1/(1+np.exp(-s))
    return f

def log_likelihood(theta, x, y, model):
    result = np.sum(y*np.log(model) + (1-y)*np.log(1-model))
    return result

def negative_log_likelihood(theta, x, y, model):
    return (-1)*log_likelihood(theta, x, y, model)

def log_likelihood_derivative(dtheta, x, y, model):    
    result = np.array(y - model(dtheta, x))
    x = np.hstack((np.ones(x.shape[0]).reshape(x.shape[0], 1), x))
    result = np.reshape(result, (-1, 1))
    result = np.sum(result*x, axis=0) 
    assert result.shape == theta.shape
    return result

def negative_log_likelihood_derivative(theta, x, y, model):
    return -log_likelihood_derivative(theta, x, y, model)
```

I am not able to resolve the problem by myself.

When I type:

```
model = logistic_func
theta_opt = so.fmin_bfgs(negative_log_likelihood, theta0, 
                         fprime=negative_log_likelihood_derivative,
                         args=(X, Y, model), disp=True)
```

I get:

> TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type function which has no callable log method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_bfgs.html):

> Parameters
>
> ```
> f callable f(x,*args)
>      Objective function to be minimized.
>
> x0 ndarray
>     Initial guess.
>
> fprime callable f'(x,*args), optional
>     Gradient of f.
> ```

`Callable` means that a function must be passed as a parameter. You, however, pass *a return value* of that function, `negative_log_likelihood_derivative(theta0, X, Y, model)` (note the round brackets that are used to call the function!). Instead you need to pass *the function itself*:

```
theta_opt = so.fmin_bfgs(negative_log_likelihood_derivative, theta0, 
                         fprime=negative_log_likelihood_derivative, 
                         args=(X,Y), disp=True)
```

Side notes:

1. You import the function by name; why do you call it from the `so` namespace?
2. You have the same functions given for `f` and `fprime`; it's usually incorrect unless `f = np.exp(x)`

Comment: @Andrew Sobolev "Add the model to your args with X, Y". Could you write how exactly to do it? I think I do not get it

Comment: Just look into the docs. The function `f` is called as `f(x,*args)`. That means, that `args` holds the rest of arguments for the function. If `negative_log_likelihood_derivative` has 4 arguments, the first has to be the independent variable, and the rest are taken from `args` tuple. So writing `args=(X, Y, model)` instead of `args=(X,Y)` should do what you want

Comment: @Andrew Sobolev I have got through docs, but not everything is clear there. That what you have wrote is understood but when I type: theta_opt = so.fmin_bfgs(negative_log_likelihood, theta0, 
                         fprime=negative_log_likelihood_derivative,
                         args=(X, Y, model), disp=True). I get error: TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type function which has no callable log method. Please help :)

Comment: What data do you store in `theta0`? How does `negative_log_likelihood` function look like?

Comment: @Andrew Sobolev I have update the post

Comment: You are aware, that your `negative_log_likelihood` function does not depend on `theta`, right? `so.fmin_bfgs(f, x)` minimizes the given function `f(x)` with respect to `x`, but your `f` does not depend on `x`

Comment: @Andrew Sobolev Not really, I thought that negative_log_likelihood depends on theta directly. Theta is in args.

Comment: @Andrew Sobolev Theta is included in model

Comment: What does that mean? The function has to depend on the argument _explicitly_. At least that's what `so.fmin_bfgs` expects.

Comment: @Andrew Sobolev Theta is explicitly included in logistic_func (I edited post), and that model is used further. You mean that I need to include logistic_func in negative_log_likelihood?

Comment: So `model` is a function, and you are trying to take a log of a _function_ (`np.log(model)`), and not of its value. You can try changing `np.log(model)` to `np.log(model(theta, x))` everywhere in the `log_likelihood` and educate yourself on Python types